# Moving a DNS server to a new IP address

Tags: dns-hosting

i have a dns server on windows 2008 x64 and i want to change its ip address.

If i keeping the DNS server name (typically "ns#.domain.com") and just moving it to a new IP address, what time it takes log to update?

and what happening if i change this ip at the next time again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very, very general:

It's all depend on your zone configuration.
If you are using in-bailiwick (the term in-bailiwick means that nameservers for a domain are in the same domain) type of configuation you need to change all your glue records in every domain for the new IP (you change that via your registar).
If you are not using glue records (out-of-bailiwick/glueless) you need prepeare you DNS name for change (lower TTL).

In both cases you should run both servers together (old and new) for some time (it's just good advice and is not a requirement).

Change (propagation) in registry takes from 24 to more hours.

Answer (score 0):

The time it takes to be updated, depends on the Refresh and TTL values you have set in the SOA record. 
Also, it is different if it is the Master or the Slave DNS server.